# tradingview economic calendar, param options for request?

Tags: python, calendar, tradingview-api

I want to make a custom request to the economic calendar from tradingview. I could not find all possible params options on the URL. How can I find/search for it? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

url : "https://economic-calendar.tradingview.com/events"
Thank You !

Sample Parameters that I found on the topic below.

```
payload = {
    'from': (today + pd.offsets.Hour(23)).isoformat() + '.000Z',
    'to': (today + pd.offsets.Day(7) + pd.offsets.Hour(22)).isoformat() + '.000Z',
    'countries': ','.join(['US', 'IN'])
}
```

[How to web scrap Economic Calendar data from TradingView and load into Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352810/how-to-web-scrap-economic-calendar-data-from-tradingview-and-load-into-dataframe)